# Запрос выдаёт ошибку ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle

В чём ошибка запроса?

Сам запрос:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE `complite_incomplite` (
    `card_task_id` INT(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `card_id` INT(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tax_code` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `reg_operation` VARCHAR(270) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `life_situation_name` VARCHAR(270) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `create_ts` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_complete` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `complete_ts` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `current_step_id` VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `prev_tax_code` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `prev_step_tax_code` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `taxpayer_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `reg_tax_code` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `in_number` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `receipt_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `registration_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `control_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `final_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `has_interim_answer` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `interim_answer_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_repeat` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `duplicate_status` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `duplicate_parent_id` INT(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `attachment_id` INT(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `attach_group_id` INT(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `card_id` (`card_id`),
    INDEX `card_task_id` (`card_task_id`),
    INDEX `attachment_id` (`attachment_id`),
    INDEX `attach_group_id` (`attach_group_id`)
);
insert into complite_incomplite
select tsk.card_task_id, tsk.card_id, tsk.tax_code,
stat.title as reg_operation,
th.title as life_situation_name,
to_char(tsk.create_ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as create_ts,
tsk.is_complete,
to_char(tsk.complete_ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as complete_ts,
st.task_step_name as current_step_id,
tsk.prev_tax_code, 
tsk.prev_step_tax_code,
npt.taxpayer_id, npt.tax_code as reg_tax_code, npt.in_number,
to_char(npt.receipt_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as receipt_date,
to_char(npt.registration_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as registration_date,
to_char(npt.control_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as control_date,
to_char(npt.final_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as final_date,
npt.has_interim_answer,
to_char(npt.interim_answer_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as interim_answer_date,
npt.is_repeat,
npt.description, npt.duplicate_status, npt.duplicate_parent_id,
att.attachment_id, att.attach_group_id
from card.t_card_task tsk
join card.t_card_task_status stat on stat.card_task_status_id = tsk.card_task_status_id
join card.t_theme th on th.theme_id = tsk.theme_id
join card.t_task_step st on st.task_step_id = tsk.current_step_id
join card.t_card npt on npt.card_id = tsk.card_id
join card.t_attachment_card_link att on att.card_id = tsk.card_id;
select * from complite_incomplite c_i
left join card.t_attachment atta on atta.attachment_id on c_i.attachment_id;
drop table complite_incomplite;
```

При выполнении вылетает ошибка:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Я так понимаю, что всё дело в `;`. Но как тогда выполнить данный запрос последовательно?

Сам запрос я запустить не могу и передаю его другому человеку, чтобы он его выполнял, но у меня нет опыта работы в Oracle.

Comment: А зачем тут временная таблица, соберите все в один запрос выборки. И да, ошибка может возникать если средство которым выполняют запрос не готово обрабатывать несколько запросов за раз. И обратные апострофы в oracle не используются  заключать в них ничего нельзя

Comment: Потому что в первой выборке соединяются данные из t1 и t2 и во второй выборке соединяются данные из t3 по данным из t2 и одним запросом это увы не выполнить

Comment: Любые данные можно получить одним запросом. `select .... from (ваш-первый-запрос) c_i left join card.t_attachment atta on atta.attachment_id on c_i.attachment_id`. Если все совсем сложно, то можно воспользоваться WITH

Comment: Но ведь одним запросом никак не получается т.к. в первом select соединяются 6 таблиц и во 2 select соединяется таблица 7 по столбцу полученному из таблицы 6. Либо я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: Так же еще вопрос: если нет прав доступа на создание таблиц можно ли как то обойти этот момент чтобы получить нужную выборку?

Comment: Я кстати не понял, почему бы просто этот left join не добавить непосредственно к первому запросу. на первый взгляд это будет равноценно join к временной таблице. По поводу запроса что я предложил выше: обратите внимание, sql позволяет в любом месте запроса вместо таблицы использовать подзапрос, предоставляющий нужные данные. так что замена временной таблицы запросом, который такую таблицу наполняет, равноценно

Comment: Хмм если сделать как вы предложили то теперь вылетела ошибка ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis в части from card.t_card_task as tsk разве когда делаешь подзапрос нужно ещё что то заключать в скобки? Помимо самого запроса

Comment: чаще всего ошибка все таки из за не сбалансированности скобок. А так сам подзапрос в скобках и после них либо сразу алиас (имя) подзапроса, либо что то вроде join и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

> но как тогда выполнить данный запрос последовательно

Последовательно, если у вас нет опыта работы с данной БД, надо начинать с небольшого воиспроизводимого примера, последовательно усложняя его. Начнём с первой строчки:

```sql
create global temporary table `testtab` (`id` int(15) null default null);
```

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Исправляем:

```sql
create global temporary table testtab (id int);

Global temporary TABLE created.
```

И так далее, пока не заработает.

Comment: я имею ввиду какие в Oracle используются разделители в запросе? Т.е. если в sql это ; то как сделать то же в Oracle? Таблица прекрасно создаётся но на этом всё заканчивается ошибкой

Comment: 1) В SQL нет никаких разделителей. Символы `;` или `/` служат как разделители отдельных запросов и определяются инструментом, которым вы эти запросы выполняете. Oracle их тоже использует. 2) _Таблица прекрасно создаётся_ - у вас три синтаксические ошибке сразу в первых строчках, что таблица создаётся -  это иллюзия.